# Entity having different relation with different security roles?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have two security roles `ProjectLead` and `Developer` ; also I have one custom entity named `Project`. Is it possible that `ProjectLead` and `Project` have 1:N relation(one `ProjectLead` can work in more than one `Project`)

and `Developer` and `Project` have 1:1 relation(one developer can work in one project)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem. You want make relationship between a role and a entity, this ins't possible and don't make any sense. You want restrict the access to projects? This can be done with roles, in Developer role for project entity you can put the read action in user option (just one level) like that the developer only viewed that project or if you have a team with many developers you that team can own that project.
For ProjectLead you can put access at Business unit level.

Comment: Thanks Pedro for reply. OK,I understand. If u could suggest me a way to make developer able to access to a project he is assign to.I guess some changes I need to do in roles.is it?

Comment: Yes, in Developer role you access to Project entity and in Read and Write privileges you put the access level in user. So a developer only can see the projects owned.